# Shiro Configuration - roles and limiting searchbase

Tags: configuration, active-directory, shiro, apache-zeppelin

We've been trying to add the right shiro configuration to ensure that a specific AD group can only log in, and also differentiate roles. We got two working solutions, but the first let's in everyone within the active directory (but the roles work fine), the second does not let in everyone but the roles do not work.

1) 
This version works for the adding roles to the specific CNs but allows everyone to login.

```
activeDirectoryRealm = org.apache.zeppelin.realm.ActiveDirectoryGroupRealm
activeDirectoryRealm.systemUsername = aduser
activeDirectoryRealm.hadoopSecurityCredentialPath = jceks://file/user/zeppelin/conf/zeppelin.jceks
activeDirectoryRealm.searchBase = OU=User Accounts,DC=domain,DC=local
activeDirectoryRealm.url = ldap://AD.domain.local:389
activeDirectoryRealm.groupRolesMap = "CN=admins,OU=User Accounts,DC=domain,DC=local":"admin"
activeDirectoryRealm.authorizationCachingEnabled = false
activeDirectoryRealm.principalSuffix = @domain.local
securityManager.realms = $activeDirectoryRealm
```

2)
This version limits down the login to the specified AD group, but does not associates roles with the group.

```
ldapADGCRealm = org.apache.zeppelin.realm.LdapRealm
ldapADGCRealm.contextFactory.systemUsername = aduser@domain.local
ldapADGCRealm.hadoopSecurityCredentialPath = jceks://file/user/zeppelin/conf/zeppelinldap.jceks
ldapADGCRealm.searchBase = "OU=User Accounts,DC=domain,DC=local"
ldapADGCRealm.userSearchBase = "OU=User Accounts,DC=domain,DC=local"
ldapADGCRealm.groupSearchBase = "OU=User Accounts,DC=domain,DC=local"
ldapADGCRealm.groupObjectClass = group
ldapADGCRealm.memberAttribute = memberUid
ldapADGCRealm.groupIdAttribute = cn
ldapADGCRealm.groupSearchEnableMatchingRuleInChain = true
ldapADGCRealm.rolesByGroup = users: admin
ldapADGCRealm.userSearchFilter = (&(objectclass=user)(sAMAccountName={0})(memberOf=CN=users,OU=User Accounts,DC=domain,DC=local))
ldapADGCRealm.contextFactory.url = ldap://AD.domain.local:389 (edited)
```

Related posts:

- https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/54896/zeppelin-ad-users-not-binded-to-groups.html
- https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/82135/how-to-limit-access-to-zeppelin-webui-based-for-sp.html

Any ideas where we go wrong?

Thanks,
Andras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better late than never)
Got role group mapping working using LdapRealm. Needed to set

```
ldapRealm.userSearchAttributeName = userPrincipalName

ldapRealm.memberAttribute = member
```

In our case userPrincipalName is the attribute in AD that contains full user name we entered (user@domain.com) and member is attribute that stores member of group.